# How to handle access_token expiry and google signin status in Google Token Model?

Tags: google-signin, google-identity, googlesigninaccount

For `google sign in`, as google deprecated the platform.js library so we are going to use the google identity service library, and get the access_token using the [Token Model](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-token-model?hl=en).

```
const client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
  client_id: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID',
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
  callback: (response) => {
    ...
  },
});
```

To trigger the UX flow, the `client.requestAccessToken();` is called on each click of the `Google signin` button.

One thing I didn't understand is how to handle the access_token expiry -

As per the doc -

`By design, access tokens have a short lifetime. If the access token expires prior to the end of the user's session, obtain a new token by calling requestAccessToken() from a user-driven event such as a button press.`

**Q.1** Does the above mean we need to call this function explicitly from the callback function? Or how would we know the access_token is expired?

Also with platform.js, we had an option to check if the user is already logged in google -

```
GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
currentUser = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();

if (currentUser && currentUser.isSignedIn()) {
   // user is already loggedin in google
} else {
   googleAuthPromise = GoogleAuth.signIn();
   googleAuthPromise.then(function (user) {
     // now user is loggedin in google
   });
}
```

**Q.2** But with the new library, these methods are not available, how can we achieve that if a user is already logged in to google (by not involving any custom session or cookie variables)?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example, in order to clarify your situation?

Comment: Hi there, I'm stuck on the exact same questions. Did you find a solution, would you mind sharing it? I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi Yes, I solved it by assigning the callback function as empty, and after I get the `accessToken` by `requestAccessToken` I assigned the callback function again.

I have listed the details here - https://weekendtutorial.com/how-to-use-google-identity-services-for-google-sign-in-in-2022/